# Inject dynamic entity to Generic repository in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

I have a generic class called BaseRepository which is injected in Admin module. I would like to pass dynamic entities at runtime in BaseRepository. But i am getting following error.

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BaseRepository (?, DataSource). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the AdminModule context.
```

```
// base.repository.ts
@Injectable()
    export class BaseRepository<T extends UserEntityInterface> implements GenericInterface<T>
    {
      constructor(modelType: ObjectType<T>, dataSource: DataSource) {
        this.modelType = modelType;
        if (dataSource !== undefined) {
        this.repository = dataSource.getRepository(this.modelType);
        }
     }

    async findAll(): Promise<T[]> {
      return (await this.repository.find()) as T[];
    }

    async save(entity: T): Promise<T> {
     return await this.repository.save(entity);
   }
}
```

```
// admin.module.ts
@Module({
    controllers: [AdminController],
     providers: [
         AdminService,
         AdminRepository,
         BaseRepository,
      ],
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AdminUsers])],
      exports: [TypeOrmModule],
    })
    export class AdminModule {}
```

```
@Injectable()
export default class AdminRepository extends BaseRepository<AdminUsers> 
{
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) 
    {
      super(AdminUsers, dataSource);
    }
}
```

In the above implementation, the highlighted issue can be solved once i pass concrete entity to the constructor using `@InjectRepository()` but since it is a generic class, i want to pass dynamic entity.

Also when i tried injecting concrete entity like `@InjectRepository(AdminUsers)`, i am getting another error.

`dataSource.getRepository is not a function`

Note that i am using "typeorm" 0.3x and "@nestjs/typeorm" - 9.x